# Multiple python installations - setting path variable

Tags: python, ipython

I have several python installations on my system, in /usr/lib/ I have python2.7, python 3, python3.2. I am trying to upgrade my version of scipy from .9. When I do a

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
```

It doesn't work saying that it's already done in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages

When I import it in ipython, however, it finds the old version of Scipy:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.pyc
```

How do I tell python to load the 3.2 version of scipy and not the 2.7? I believe this has something to do with the PYTHONPATH variable, but I'm not sure which one to change.

James

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer, but you should better use virtualenv, it will save you much time: http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell python to load the 3.2 version of scipy and not the 2.7

Every python version manages its own set of installed modules. The idea is to invoke the `pip` executable that belongs to the right python version.

From what you described it seems that you have installed the ipython module in your `python2.7` interpreter, but your pip executable belongs to the `python3.2` interpreter.

The easiest way to execute `python2.7`'s `pip` is:

```
sudo ipython -m pip install --upgrade scipy
```

However this installs scipy as root into your system files and thus usually interferes with versions installed by package managers.

An arguably better way is to install packages in your user's home directory.

```
ipython -m pip install --upgrade scipy --user
```

As pointed out in the comments, probably the best way is to get familiar with `virtualenv`.

I myself find `anaconda` particularly appealing, since it comes with a clean way of installing and managing multiple python interpreters with a focus on scientific packages across many platforms.